# Problems with deploying a load balancer in front of etcd clusters

Tags: google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

i am trying to deployu a load balancer in front of 3 of my etcd clusters which are running on port 2379. But I am always getting a connection refused error. I ve added firewall IPs for healthchecks and added a fw rule for 0.0.0.0 on port 2379 but still having this issue.
Is deploying an internal LB to load balance to servers in backend serving on port 2379 too difficult, am I missing something ?

Anyone had this type of issue before ?

Comment: Could you please share where you're getting this connection refused error (separate GCP/GKE Cluster)? And at what point of the configuration? Can you sanitize the configuration and are you able to provide the yaml file?. Have you setup separate per-cluster [etcd CA trust](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-trust#etcd). Can you run the service using -v(turning on verbosity and see what was the error showing. Are you able to [curl <ILB_IP>](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#using)from the VM instance behind the cluster.

Comment: Furthermore, from ILB side, are you connecting from the same region, if not, have you considered optional [“global access”](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#global_access_beta) parameter for ILB to allow access for any region.

Comment: Additionally[considerations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#considerations_for_existing_ingresses) for existing ingresses, [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#restrictions_for_internal_tcpudp_load_balancers) and [limits](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#limits).

Answer (score 1):

ok, thank you guys who contributed to my problem, here s the problem and the solution, it s because of the nature of gcp load balancers i think.

Here is the earlier etcd config and the latest config.. as soon as i changed the config, LBs started routing trrafic

Earlier:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \\
  --name $ETCD_NAME \\
  --discovery-srv bstock.local \\
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://$INTERNAL_IP:2380 \\
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \\
  --initial-cluster-state new \
  --advertise-client-urls http://$INTERNAL_IP:2379 \\
  --listen-peer-urls http://$INTERNAL_IP:2380 \\
  --listen-client-urls http://$INTERNAL_IP:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \\
  --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd

Latest:

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \\
  --name $ETCD_NAME \\
  --discovery-srv bstock.local \\
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://$INTERNAL_IP:2380 \\
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \\
  --initial-cluster-state new \
  --advertise-client-urls http://$INTERNAL_IP:2379 \\
  --listen-peer-urls http://$INTERNAL_IP:2380 \\
  --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 \\
  --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
```